# How do I render an image through OnSubmit() instead on OnChange() in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My intention is to select an image file and then render the image only another button is clicked. Am trying to store to store the event values (file path) across components but unable to do it. Is there an easier way to this?
Am unable to figure out how I can store the file from the event.target.files in the OnChange() function and use it in OnSubmit() event. My current code snippet is as follows:

```
handleIMageChange(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];

    reader.onloadend = () => {
      this.setState({
        file: file,
        reader
      });
    }
}

handleImgSubmit(event){
  let reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = () => {
  this.setState( prevState => {
  return {
    file: prevState.file,
    imagePreviewUrl: prevState.reader.result
  }
  })
  }
  alert(this.state.file);
reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.file);
event.preventDefault();
}

render(){
  return(
  <div className="pagecontainer">
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={ myTheme }>

  <div className="column2">
  <input type="file" id="myimage" onChange={this.handleIMageChange.bind(this)} />
  <input type="submit" value="upload" onClick={this.handleImgSubmit}/>

  {this.state.value}
  <Image  src={this.state.imagePreviewUrl} />
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the outcome you get? Where is `state.imagePreviewUrl` being displayed?

Comment: I am using imagePreviewUrl as src <Image ..> in the render function.

I see the following error:
TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsDataURL is not an object.

at the code:
    reader.readAsDataURL(String(this.state.file));

Answer (score 0):

for the handleImageChange function you are setting the imagePreviewUrl, you can just save the reader class output to a property on state and on submit change update the imagePreviewUrl

```
handleImageChange(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let file = event.target.files[0];

  reader.onloadend = () => {
    this.setState({
      file,
    });
  }
}


handleImgSubmit(event){
  let file = this.state.file;
  let reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = () => {
    this.setState( prevState => {
      return {
        imagePreviewUrl: reader.result
      }
    })
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)

  event.preventDefault();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about prevState. But it still fails in readAsDataURL(String(this.state.file) with the same error

Comment: sorry for all the edits, it should be readAsDataURL(this.state.file)

Comment: ah okay, you are preventing default which is blocking the file upload. I think if you console log out the file in the state that gets saved, its not a file. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: the state of the file seems to be undefined in OnSubmit(). If I try to call readAsDataURL() in OnChange() it works fine, somehow am not able to store the file object across events.

Comment: react does use event pooling, you may have to clone the file so the reference to it doesn't get cleared. `let file = { ...event.target.files[0] }`